# Get the material element classList observable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using `mat-autocomplete`, and I want to unfocus the input after selecting the element without any click. The `mat-focused` class of `mat-form-field` causes the focus on `mat-auto-complete`, by removing it from `mat-form-field` I did it, but the `mat-focused` class takes a little time to set and I need to wait until it is set that I can remove it, I solved it by using `setTimeout`, but I think it's not correct. How can I change it to async or get the async function, promise, observable or... from material and not use `setTimeOut`?

Component:

```
export class AutocompleteSimpleExample {
  myControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
  public matForm ;
  constructor(){

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.matForm =  document.getElementById("matForm") 
  }
  options = [
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Three'
   ];

  test(option){
    console.log(option)
    setTimeout(function(){
      this.matForm.classList.remove('mat-focused' )}, 100);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width test" #matForm id="matForm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" #textInput>
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="test($event.option)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{ option }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

I made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zi4ofc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change the CSS class yourself. That's not how Angular works.

Instead, rely on the framework itself : create a view child element and `blur` on it, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zi4ofc-mf3yzu?file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.ts) :

```
@ViewChild('textInput') textInput: ElementRef;  
test(option) {
  console.log(option.value)
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.textInput.nativeElement.blur();
  });
}
```